# git desktop doesn't show all remote repository's

Tags: git, github

i'm having trouble with the git desktop app.

i have a few repo's on my personal github page and i'm also part of 1 repo from an organization. but when i open the git desktop app it only shows the repo from this organization. how can i make sure i can see the repo's from my personal account to?

i have already looked on google and youtube but there everyone seems to just get all all their repo's when they connect to github with the app.

i cant post pictures because i dont have enough reputation but i can do this http://snag.gy/D0wxT.jpg and this is my personal github page https://github.com/gvr37leo (notice the organization in the bottom left that containts the only showing repo)

Comment: Note that Git and GitHub are different things. Git is a fully open-source SCM with an official command-line client (`git`) and a couple of graphical tools (`gitk` and `git-gui`). GitHub is a company with several proprietary products including a cloud-based Git repository host and some graphical clients. You are using *GitHub for Windows*.

Comment: Paul - actually you're using GitHub desktop, the new successor to GitHub for Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found out wat the problem was.
i was supposed to clone my repo's from github.

well this fixes my problem i dont understand why the organization repo was present and the others werent, but whatever.

Comment: @PaulBoon note that what most experienced git users do is have a single local repo with *multiple* remote repos attached, then you can choose which one to push/pull, etc from.